# Are there any limitations and drawbacks of early publication in USPTO

Tags: uspto, uspublication

I filed a patent application last month in USPTO through my attorney (I am not a US citizen) . I am now planning to go for early publication. Is this possible now?

Also are there any limitations or drawbacks of early publication? Especially since I will be filing in many other countries.

Please enlighten me.

Relevant clause:

[1129    Request for Early Publication](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1129.html)

Comment: Has the information already been made publicly available ? Once it is you are too late to file anywhere else in the world.

Comment: @George White  Do you mean if I go for early publication, and lets say it is published in 4 months, then I will not be able to file the same patent anywhere else in the world ?

Comment: Most places in the world require absolute novelty on the day of filing in that country. However there is an international agreement that filing in one country while there is still absolute novelty gives you a year to file everywhere else.